# Como controlar o volume a mídia do app no Android

Tags: java, android

Estou como uma duvida de como controlar o volume da mídia do app.

Estou utilizando este método:

```
Button button1;
MediaPlyer mp;
button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(Teste.this, R.raw.som);
    mp.start();
}

});
```

Eu queria ao diminuir ou aumentar o volume no aparelho, alteraria do app e não do celular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adiciona na(s) Activity que tu pretende que seja mudado o volume da mídia ao invés da campainha o método abaixo:

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        setVolumeControlStream (AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    }
```

O método `onStart()` faz referência a quando o aplicativo é iniciado.

Existem mais informações nesses links abaixo:

[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628659/how-can-i-manage-audio-volumes-sanely-in-my-android-app/674207#674207)

[link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539264/volume-control-in-android-application)

Answer (score 3):

Para controlar o volume da tua aplicação no MediaPlayer, podes usar o método "setVolume"

`// Volume baixo em ambos os lados (Esquerdo e direito)
mp.setVolume(0,0)`

Para saber mais sobre este método, visite: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setVolume(float, float)

Comment: blz, mas o eu queria era controlar o volume da aplicação no aparelho físico, pois quando você aperta para aumentar o volume ele aumenta do aparelho e não do app, para conseguir aumentar o volume da aplicação e só quando está ativa (quando você chama o som ), porém não da muito tempo, pois são sons muito curto.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html).

Exemplo de uso:

```
AudioManager audio = (AudioManager)  
        getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, VALOR, 0); // Valor: 0~15
```